# MailChimp templates are worthless with PHP

Tags: php, email, templates, send, mailchimp

I've just downloaded mail templates from [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com/resources/html-email-templates/). But when I send them with PHP the html tag, headers and all css styles are removed when I view message in Gmail and mail is useless.

As far as I know I need to make css inline not in headers.

But it still confuses me why MailChimp offers such templates that does not work?

**SOLUTION:**
I've just found out that MailChimp offers [CSS inliner tool](http://beaker.mailchimp.com/inline-css). Nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send e-mail generated by your PHP to MailChimp through MailChimp API there is one parameter saying that you want to inline you CSS automatically by MailChimp. Otherwise headers are cutted out.

Comment: I am not sending via MailChimp api. I handle it alone. So if understand you right this templates are specially just for sending via MailChimp and if you want to send it alone you have to make inline css? Right?

Comment: Exactly. You can use MailChimp inliner tool to do it for you http://beaker.mailchimp.com/inline-css